# Node.js high memory usage

Tags: mysql, node.js, memory-leaks

I'm currently running a node.js server that communicates with a remote MySQL database as well as performs webrequests to various APIs. When the server is idle, the CPU usage ranges from 0-5% and RAM usage at around 300MB. Yet when the server is under load, the RAM usage linearly goes up and CPU usage jumps all around and even up to 100% at times.

I setup a snapshot solution that that would take a snapshot of the heap when a leak was detected using node-memwatch. I downloaded 3 different snapshots when the server was at 1GB 1.5GB and 2.5GB RAM usage and attempted to analyze them yet I have no idea where the problem is because the total amount of storage in the analytics seem to add up to something much lower.

Here is one of the snapshots, when the server had a memory usage of 1107MB.

https://i.gyazo.com/e3dadeb727be3bdb4eeb833094291ebf.png

Does that match up? From what I see there is only a maximum of 500 MB allocated to objects there. Also, would anyone have any ideas of the crazy CPU usage that I'm getting? Thanks.

Comment: it's about how code is effective, nobody can predict it without seeing code. cuz there are many reasons why it works as You explained. can You share with us the part of code? or You can do request to me: https://hackhands.com/num8er/   I'll find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is better tool to proper diagnose that leak, Looks like you can get some help using N|Solid https://nodesource.com/products/nsolid , it will help you to visualize and monitor your app, is free to use in a develop environment.